# Unable to connect to AWS mysql RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-workbench, aws, amazon-web-services

I created an AWS mySQL RDS instance (free tier), but i am unable to connect to it from workbench or cli. I have enabled public access to the DB while creation and allowed "All traffic" while trying to debug. Following are the DB details -

[image]

The DB is configured to use the default security group

[image]

Following is the error i get when i try accessing via cli

```
MySQL  JS > \connect admin@db.abcd.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
Creating a session to 'admin@db.abcd.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306'
Enter password: 
MySQL Error 2003 (Can't connect to MySQL server on '<db>.<..>.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (60)): HY000
```

I used telnet to check connectivity but got an error -

```
telnet db.abcd.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
db.abcd.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I am new to AWS and this seems like an easy thing. Can you pls help me with fixing this?

Comment: Clearly you're trying to use an incorrect hostname.

Comment: the endpoint is just a placeholder in the question above. I wanted to hide it since i have enabled public access :)

Comment: And it's **the "real" one** that is incorrect: that's the meaning of "nodename nor servname provided, or not known".